# Activiti: Only run timer jobs associated with a specific process definition ID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I have two services running an activiti engine, each deploy a different process definition. processX is deployed by serviceX and processY is deployed by serviceY. processX and processY both have timer events that call a service method in serviceX and serviceY respectively.

I am running into an issue where the job for process**X** gets picked up by service**Y** and the job for process**Y** gets picked up by service**X**.

As per https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#async_executor_design this is expected behavior.  All running instances of the activiti engine pointing to the same schema poll the job table and execute whatever is on top of the stack, regardless of process definition ID.

Is there any way to specify in the activiti configuration that only jobs associated with a specific process definition ID should be executed by a given instance of the engine?

Comment: Would it be possible to specify a lock owner and achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible

Activiti's architecture is built in such a manner that **EVERY** app sharing an Activiti DB and running an instance of the activiti engine should be able to execute **ANY** job stored in the activiti database

If you have different apps, only capable of executing specific jobs, they should be backed by **DIFERENT** Activiti DBs

Kinda of seems like a design oversight to me, but then again maybe I am abusing the arch